# ConfigurationManager: always key-value pairs?

Tags: c#, wpf, configurationmanager

I try to use ConfigurationManager to configure my c# app.
Is it always so, that CM only does key-value pairs?
like with

```
 <add key="k1" value="v1"/>
```

or can I also use items like

```
 <God Name="Shiva" Spouse="Parvati" Legs="2 Arms="6"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are custom configuration sections that you can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationsection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Replace `CustomSection` with `God` and you're set. You need to write the extra code to read them if course, but it's totally doable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>  
   <configSections>
     <section name="CustomSection" type="Samples.AspNet. CustomSection, CustomConfigurationSection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" restartOnExternalChanges="true" />
   </configSections>  

   <CustomSection fileName="default.txt" maxUsers="1000" maxIdleTime="00:15:00" /> 

 </configuration>
```

Another excellent example can be found here: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/net-custom-configuration-section-collection-and-elements/

Beware though. Configuration should be used for application constants. God's and their abilities look like a better fit for a data source (though I guess it was just an example).